# find exponential line going through 3 points

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function

I have 3 points:(0,0);(55,64);(137,200)

How could i get the formula going through those 3 points?

They line up in an exponential line like this one:
[image]

Comment: No exponential is going to go through $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the exponential as $f(x) = C \cdot a^{kx}$. Plugging your points, we get a non-linear $3 \times 3$ system on $C,a$ and $k$, which, in general, I don't think can be solved without numerical methods and approximations (i.e., using a calculator, matlab, Taylor series, etc)

Comment: $a$ and $k$ are redundant.  $a^{kx}=\exp(kx \log (a) )$